# Определить, можно ли вставить изображение

Tags: python, алгоритм, изображения

Задача - узнать в какое место я могу вставить изображение на макет. Под "местом" подразумеваются координаты верхней левой точки изображения.

Макет - это просто однотонное изображение x*y размером.

Изображения на макет добавляются в цикле. Изображение может быть от 1*1 пикселя размером, до x*y.
Изображения не могут наезжать друг на друга, не могу выезжать за пределы макета.
Цвет изображения может быть любым, кроме RGB(0, 0, 0) - цвета макета
Есть рабочий метод, но он не оптимальный и занимает очень много времени, особенно для маленьких изображений на большом макете.

Данных достаточно много.

Как я могу улучшить метод? Или какое есть решение задачи?

Так же я могу получить список уже вставленных в макет изображений с их позициями.

```
# возращает кортеж из доступных точек для размещения изображения
# размещение на этих точках гарантирует, что одно изображение не налазит на другой
#
# где logo_size - размер изображения, которое пытаются вставить,
# mask - макет, на котором обозначены изображения
# template_size - размер макета
def get_availible_top_left_dot(logo_size, mask: Image) -> []:
    # вычитаем длину и высоту логотипа, чтобы отсечь позиции, которых в принципе быть не может
    width = mask.width - logo_size[0]
    height = mask.width - logo_size[1]
    good_dots = list()
    for x in range(width):
       # print('x: ' + x.__str__() + '/' + width.__str__())
        for y in range(height):
            # пытаемся разместить лого
            a = x
            b = y
            # изначально - ширина изображения. Если уменьшилось до 0, то изображение влезло
            good_row = logo_size[0]
            for a in range(width):
                for b in range(height):
                    # если не получилось, то сбросить счётчик ширины
                    pixel = mask.getpixel((a, b))
                    if pixel == (255, 255, 255):
                        print(pixel)
                        good_row = logo_size[0]
                        break
                    elif b == logo_size[1]:
                        good_row = good_row-1
                        break
                    good_row = good_row - 1
                if good_row < 1:
                    good_dots.append((x, y))
                    break

       # print(good_dots)
    return good_dots
```

Comment: Задача в том, чтобы упаковать как можно больше прямоугольников на лист? Тогда это 2d bin packing problem. Если только для одного место найти - то выбрать BSP структуру (2d segment tree? r-tree?) , удобную для поиска свободного прямоугольника.

Comment: @MBo, спасибо, теперь понятно куда гуглить и задача сильно упростилась (: